# Cannot use python ctypes to load C++ share library

Tags: python, c++

I follow instructions of this page to try to call C++ functions.
[Calling C/C++ from Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145270/calling-c-c-from-python)

I write a **pylib.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
public:
    void bar() {
        std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
    }
};

extern "C" {
    Foo* Foo_new() { return new Foo(); }
    void Foo_bar(Foo* foo) { foo->bar(); }
}
```

and then use these commands on Win 10 terminal:

```
g++ -c -fPIC pylib.cpp -o pylib.o
g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,pylib.so -o pylib.so  pylib.o
```

I get the message in the terminal. Just a warning. The **pylib.so** still be maked by g++.

```
pylib.cpp:1:0: warning: -fPIC ignored for target (all code is position independent)
 #include <iostream>
 ^
```

I write a **pylib.py**:

```
from ctypes import *

lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('pylib.so')
f = lib.Foo()
f.bar()
```

I got the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Jack/PycharmProjects/dip_hw1/pylib.py", line 3, in <module>
    lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('pylib.so')
  File "C:\Python\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 426, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "C:\Python\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 1114] 動態連結程式庫 (DLL) 初始化例行程序失敗。
```

OSError: [WinError 1114] **動態連結程式庫 (DLL) 初始化例行程序失敗。**
this meaning likes
OSError: [WinError 1114] **Dynamic-link library (DLL) initialization routine failed**

My environment is

```
Python: Python 3.6.6 (v3.6.6:4cf1f54eb7, Jun 27 2018, 03:37:03) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
C/C++ Compiler: TDM-GCC MinGW
OS: Win 10
```

I can load C library well. but I continue get **dll error** after trying a lot of various methods to write the C++ code, or to make share library with different way.

---

**Note that:** the name of cpp library changes to `pylib2.dll`. whatever I use `.so` for `.dll` for dll file name, I get the same error.

This is the command example

```
C:\Users\Jack\PycharmProjects\dip_hw1>dir
 磁碟區 C 中的磁碟沒有標籤。
 磁碟區序號:  1AB4-8568

 C:\Users\Jack\PycharmProjects\dip_hw1 的目錄

2018/09/20  下午 03:26    <DIR>          .
2018/09/20  下午 03:26    <DIR>          ..
2018/09/20  下午 10:49    <DIR>          .idea
2018/09/18  上午 11:12    <DIR>          image
2015/06/28  下午 02:28            58,880 libatomic-1.dll
2015/06/28  下午 02:28            69,120 libatomic_64-1.dll
2013/09/01  上午 09:38           149,207 libcharset-1.dll
2015/06/28  上午 05:50           145,934 libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll
2015/06/28  下午 02:28           114,176 libgcc_s_seh_64-1.dll
2015/06/28  下午 02:28           120,832 libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll
2015/06/28  下午 02:28           934,400 libiconv-2.dll
2014/04/27  上午 06:46           484,613 libintl-8.dll
2015/06/28  下午 02:28           359,936 libquadmath-0.dll
2015/06/28  下午 02:28           354,816 libquadmath_64-0.dll
2015/06/28  下午 02:28            13,824 libssp-0.dll
2015/06/28  下午 02:28            18,944 libssp_64-0.dll
2015/06/28  下午 02:28         1,374,208 libstdc++-6.dll
2015/06/28  下午 02:28         1,405,952 libstdc++_64-6.dll
2015/06/28  下午 02:28            11,264 libvtv-0.dll
2015/06/28  下午 02:28            15,872 libvtv_64-0.dll
2015/06/28  下午 02:28            11,264 libvtv_stubs-0.dll
2015/06/28  下午 02:28            15,872 libvtv_stubs_64-0.dll
2015/06/28  下午 02:28            60,928 libwinpthread-1.dll
2015/06/28  下午 02:28            64,512 libwinpthread_64-1.dll
2018/09/17  下午 04:55             1,918 main.cpython-36.pyc
2018/09/19  下午 12:14            10,587 main.py
2018/09/19  下午 08:11           113,157 pylib.dll
2018/09/20  下午 03:26               188 pylib.py
2018/09/19  下午 11:02         2,695,132 pylib2.dll
2018/09/19  下午 11:07         2,695,135 pylib2.so
2018/09/17  下午 04:56                26 run.bat
2018/09/19  下午 02:05               627 test.py
2018/09/17  下午 04:55    <DIR>          __pycache__
              28 個檔案      11,301,324 位元組
               5 個目錄  171,916,886,016 位元組可用

C:\Users\Jack\PycharmProjects\dip_hw1>python pylib.py
C:\Users\Jack\PycharmProjects\dip_hw1
C:\Users\Jack\PycharmProjects\dip_hw1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pylib.py", line 7, in <module>
    lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('pylib2.dll')
  File "C:\Python\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 426, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "C:\Python\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 1114] 動態連結程式庫 (DLL) 初始化例行程序失敗。
```

And this is the new **pylib.py** code

```
from ctypes import *
import os
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
print(dir_path)
print(os.getcwd())

lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('pylib2.dll')
f = lib.Foo()
f.bar()
```

Comment: Is this a windows DLL or as Posix shared object you have created?  Do you have all the DLLs that pylib.so references available (on the path basically) - check with depends.exe (if you don't know what that is, search for it and download it **now** - it's a vital tool in a Windows developer's armoury).

Comment: What platform are you on? For Window's Id advise Microsoft Visual Studio Community (free), or at least some tool rather than manual command lines, and you certainly want a DLL, not an so.

Comment: If **pylib.so** is a C share library which is build by **gcc** command, then cdll.LoadLibrary('pylib.so') work. So it's seem to not require .dll.

Comment: I survey a lot of ctypes usages, they all use command line. Not using any certain IDE like Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using gcc from MinGW to compile and link the code. Since the code uses the C++ standard library (`#include <iostream>` resp. `std::cout`), you need to make the `libstdc++-6.dll` file available which ships with gcc. Copy the .dll into the working directory, then it should work.

Comment: I use g++ to compile.

Comment: Yes, using g++ is correct. _gcc_ stands for GNU Compiler Collection and the C++ compiler of gcc is g++.

Comment: I will get error when I use gcc to compile the .cpp code.

Comment: Oh! So I need to find and copy libstdc++-6.dll into the directory that the .so file locate? I think it is the working directory you talk about.

Comment: You need to copy `libstdc++-6.dll` into the *working directory*. Since you are using `cdll.LoadLibrary('pylib.so')` to load the library, the working directory also seems to be the directory that contains the .so file. The .dll is probably located in a bin/ directory somewhere near g++.exe.

Comment: I copy all the .dll in the `TDM-GCC-64\bin` to the working directory. But I get the same dll error again...

Comment: I use `os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))` to locate working directory. I find the dir is `C:\Users\Jack\PycharmProjects\dip_hw1`. I put all the .dll into `dip_hw1`.

Comment: The working directory can be seen with `os.getcwd()`. What does this function return for you?

Comment: The same `C:\Users\Jack\PycharmProjects\dip_hw1`

Comment: Strange that it didnt work. I could reproduce the exact same error (except for the chinese translation) and copying the dll fixed it for me.

Comment: I write the command example up to main question. You could check that for whether I do some mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

I find the solution by myself. The solution is:

1. Using [MinGW](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/) comipler or Microsoft C/C++ compiler.
2. Using Python 32 bit interpreter.
3. It is not necessary to copy dll from compiler bin folder.

First, I used the [TDM-GCC MinGW Compiler](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tdm-gcc/) as C/C++ compiler before. Then I try 
another compiler: [MinGW](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/). I can't tell you what different between them, I'm not a pro guy. But they produce different error message when I use `ctypes` to load the two different dll library which compile by both in the `Python 3.6.6 64 bit` interpreter. They all failed on `Python 3.6.6 64 bit` interpreter.

I try 32-bit python to load dll library. It successes to load library.
The **pylib.cpp** code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Foo {
public:
    void bar() {
        cout << "Hello" << endl;
    }
};

extern "C" {
    Foo* Foo_new() { return new Foo(); }
    void Foo_bar(Foo* foo) { foo->bar(); }
}
```

Compile command:

```
g++ -shared -o pylib.dll pylib.cpp
```

The **pylib.py** code:

```
from ctypes import *

lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('pylib.dll')
f = lib.Foo_new()
lib.Foo_bar(f)
```

The ouput:

```
Hello
```

Thanks for pschill and others propose new methods.

Comment: I had to use `lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('./pylib.dll')` to convince ctypes I wasn't looking for a system library.